# Make, setting variables from file, assignment issues

Tags: bash, shell, variables, makefile, global-variables

I have the following code working when defined at the top of my make file, it reads the contents of a file and parses the text into variables correctly:

```
VER_VAR:=$(shell cat output/target/version.txt)
FILENAME_BIN=$(word 1, $(VER_VAR)).$(word 2, $(VER_VAR)).$(word 3, $(VER_VAR)).bin
FILENAME_JFFS2=$(word 1, $(VER_VAR)).$(word 2, $(VER_VAR)).$(word 3, $(VER_VAR)).jffs2
```

Format of the file read:

```
str1 str2 1.1.0_nightlybuild (1389:1497M@trunk)
```

However I want to move this code into a function like so:

```
define EXAMPLE
    VER_VAR:=$(shell cat output/target/version.txt)
    FILENAME_BIN=$(word 1, $(VER_VAR)).$(word 2, $(VER_VAR)).$(word 3, $(VER_VAR)).bin
    FILENAME_JFFS2=$(word 1, $(VER_VAR)).$(word 2, $(VER_VAR)).$(word 3, $(VER_VAR)).jffs2
endef
```

This causes an error:

```
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `VER_VAR:=str1 str2 1.1.0_nightlybuild (1389:1497M@trunk)'
make: *** [/home/buildmaster/svn_main/buildroot/output/images/rootfs.ext2] Error 1
```

Couple of questions. Why does this cause an error in a function and not at the top of the file. How do I fix this? I have tried quotations etc and that just leads to more errors.

For example if I try:

```
VER_VAR:="$(shell cat output/target/version.txt)"
```

I get:

```
VER_VAR:="str1 str2 1.1.0_nightlybuild (1389:1497M@trunk)"
/bin/bash: VER_VAR:=str1 str2 1.1.0_nightlybuild (1389:1497M@trunk): command not found
```

Calling example:

```
# Alter the post-gen hooks, depending on what options are selected
ifneq ($(BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_BOOTIMAGE),)
    ROOTFS_EXT2_POST_GEN_HOOKS += EXAMPLE
endif
```

Comment: How are you invoking `EXAMPLE`? Inside a rule?

Comment: @Beta as a post-gen hook in buildroot. I've added in the code.